# How to handle this new user accidentally making multiple accounts and suggesting edits to their own question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, new-users, suggested-edits

I just [improved an edit](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/61534) from the suggested edits queue and I am trying to work out if I did the right thing.

The [original question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/157020/48759) is by a new user with 1 reputation. It was closed by Rubiksmoose for lacking a system/edition. [The edit](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/revisions/157020/2) added a lot of good information and clarified the question, however it was done by another new user with 1 reputation. (Now 3 by the approved edit).

To me it seems clear that the edit was made by the OP and they have accidentally made multiple accounts. (I left [a comment](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/157020/sneak-attack-on-whirlwind-attack#comment408986_157020) to let them know). My reasoning is that the edit clearly contains information that is was impossible to know without being the OP.

I know by approved/improving the edit I was in a grey area but I choose to do it in the name of newby friendliness since it wouldn't be easy to explain to them *why* the edits were rejected without causing frustration.

However, I am also concerns that I may have inadvertently approved the high-jacking of a user's first question and causing the negative first impression that was the very thing I was trying to avoid.

**What should I have done here?**

Answer (score 8):

I've rolled back the suggested edit, as it's not clear whether the suggested edit was by the same user that made the original post. While you might be right that it is the same user, you yourself have realized it *could* be a different user "hijacking" the post inadvertently in an overzealous attempt to improve it.

Because it's not obvious whether it *is* the same user, it should essentially be considered "guessing" until the querent can confirm one way or another. If [skillcheckrpg](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/59362/skillcheckrpg) is indeed the accidentally-created second account of [Mitch](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/59350/mitch), we can wait until the accounts are merged and then get clarification from the author (skillcheckrpg doesn't have the reputation to comment on questions by other users).

Comment: That's fair. I didn't vote to reopen as I thought that might be the resolution. I couldn't figure out what to do from the suggested edit page though. I didn't want the information to be lost as a rejected edit.

Comment: @linksassin: Unfortunately, I'm not sure there's an easy solution there. The best bet might be to copy the [review URL](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/61534) while you're looking at it in the review queue, reject the edit, and leave a comment/ask on meta (as you did) with a link to the suggested edit for reference.

Comment: If we reject an edit, is there a way for it to be later be accepted? By flagging or similar?

Comment: @linksassin: Not to my knowledge. But if you have a link to the suggested edit review page, you can view the markdown version and simply copy the relevant markdown from there.